# Why can't I return a figure when scraping html page?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, python-requests, lxml

I am trying to extract the 24hr Volumes from [this](https://swyftx.com/au/buy/bitcoin/) page. They have an [API](https://docs.swyftx.com.au/#/reference/charts/bar-charts/get-bar-chart) except it seems as though volume isn't returned in the json data (at least I can't get it to work). I have tried simple scraping using regex and am now using the `lxml` xpath methond.

What can I do to get the 24hr volume from this page?? Is it protected?

This is my latest code:

```
from lxml import html
import requests

swyftx_page = requests.get('https://swyftx.com/au/buy/bitcoin/')
swyftx_tree = html.fromstring(swyftx_page.content)
swyftx_prices_btc = swyftx_tree.xpath('/html/body/section[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/h3/text()')
print(swyftx_prices_btc)
```

When I run this, I get:

```
['$0.00']
```

Which is obviously not right. I am expecting an answer like:

```
['34,560,324,200']
```

Comment: Does that page use javascript?  If you fetch a page with `requests`, javascript is not processed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data you see on the page is loaded from external URL via JavaScript. To simulate it via `requests` module, you can use this example:

```py
import json
import requests


url = "https://apic.swyftx.io/markets/aud/"

data = requests.get(url).json()

# uncomment to print all data:
# print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))


for d in data:
    if d["name"] == "Bitcoin":
        print("Volume:", d["volume24H"])
        break
```

Prints:

```
Volume: 34974203469
```

Comment: This is awesome, thank you @Andrej Kesely. Can I ask how you found out it was loaded from external URL via JavaScript? Also how did you get that "https://apic.swyftx.io/markets/aud/" URL?

Comment: @PW1990 When you open Firefox Developer Tools->Network Tab (or in Chrome) you will see all requests the page is doing. One of the request is this API call.

Answer (score -1):

Disable Javascript for this page in your browser. As you can see the 24h volume is initially set to $0.00. This means that it must be updated later using Javascript. You can try to find what network access is made and access that instead.